# run a local script as root on remote server

Tags: bash, ssh, sh, sudo

I try to run a local script on multiple remote servers as root. I don't have su to root on those but just can run root commands using sudo. So far I tried:

```
for host in $(cat hosts_list); do ssh -tt $host "echo mypassword | sudo bash -s" < ./myscript.sh
```

And in myscript.sh there is something like:

```
echo "test test123" >> /etc/tests
exit 0
```

But it looks like not working and won't change the file. What is the proper way to run this script as root and without typing password separately for each host?

Comment: I think this would be a better fit on ServerFault

Comment: I believe this is a purely shell scripting question.

Comment: Try `sudo echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and then `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: As suggestion, you can take a look to ansible http://docs.ansible.com, I think it fits perfectly with your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then why do you "echo mypassword" ?

Can't you add your SSH account to the sudoers file with `NOPASSWD` ?

From `man sudoers`:

```
 authenticate      If set, users must authenticate themselves via a password (or other means
                   of authentication) before they may run commands.  This default may be
                   overridden via the PASSWD and NOPASSWD tags.  This flag is on by default.
```

Comment: I know I can run a local script on remote server like indicated here:

   http://serverfault.com/questions/617116/run-local-script-over-ssh

But the thing is in above example root access to the server is allowed. In my environment it is not. So I need to run my local script with sudo and just wanted to know if it would be possible without typing a password for each host separately

Comment: Ok, I didn't get the point at first. I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: I can already connect remote server passwordless using my own user.  But root access nor su -   not allowed. 

So I need to find a way to run my local script using sudo and not typing my sudo password every time because I need to do it for more than 300 servers.

Comment: That sounds to be exactly the purpose of `NOPASSWD` tag in sudoers.

Comment: @JavaRed The sudoers file has *nothing* to do with `ssh`; editing this eliminates the need to type your password for the `sudo` command. (That said, completely eliminating the need for a password is probably overkill; you should try to configure `sudo` to only run this particular command without a password.)